# How do I open Try value in scala and add its values by mapping them

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I have some function that returns `Try` of some case class and I want to check if something came back in the `Try` I want to use its value and add it to a list, my code looks like this:

```
val resultLines = csvDataReader.iteratorWithHeaders.map(row => {
  val someTry = fonctionThatReturnsTryOfSomeCaseClass(someArgument)
  row ++ "key" -> someTry.map(a => a.someVal).getOrElse("")
})
```

my desired output is that to have `resultLines` be full with the rows, but the `resultLines` comes out as empty iterator...

it dosent really work, I get this error:

> Error during generated code invocation:
>   com.intellij.debugger.engine.evaluation.EvaluateException: Method
>   threw 'java.lang.IllegalAccessError' exception.

Comment: could you provide more details? 
what is your desired output?

Comment: @ig-melnyk you right sorry, added the requested output

Comment: @joe What is the type of `row`? Is it a map?

Comment: are you sure you this isn't an issue with repl or the debugger? have you tried just running the program regularly?

Comment: Try to prepare http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve It is unclear what `iteratorWithHeaders` returns, what type `row` is, there is no example output and I don't understand what is the problem, you get an empty iterator or an error?

Answer (score 0):

You can can convert the `Try` to an `Option`. You can then tread the `Option` as `List`. The list will have one element if the `Try` success and zero elements if it fails.

```
scala> Try{1}.toOption.toList
res1: List[Int] = List(1)

scala> Try{1/0}.toOption.toList
res2: List[Int] = List()
```

You can append it to anther list like this:

```
List(1,2,3) ++ Try{1/0}.toOption.toList // Nothing is added since Try fails
res3: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3) 

List(1,2,3) ++ Try{1}.toOption.toList // Element added
res4: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 1)
```

Comment: It looks like OP is adding a single pair to a map, then `row + (key -> opt.getOrElse(""))` would do, no need for list.

Comment: Honestly the OP question is pretty hard to understand. I think I know what he wants to do but giving an answer to that will be unlikely to help anyone else in the future. I tried to give a more generic answer to the more generic problem. He can take the list and make it k,v pairs and append it to a Map if that what he wants to do.

Comment: Now that you pointed this out I noticed the question can't be responded without serious guessing...